# Javascript or css onclick function hide

Tags: javascript, css

I have the href: `<a class="like_counter_wrap fl_l" onclick="openFullList();">`

I need to hide the function **`openFullList();`**. How to do this?

Ok, the code:

```
<!--Vk.com-->
<div class='scVK scSB'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?49'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>VK.init({apiId: 2010456, onlyWidgets: true});</script>
<div id='vk_like'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
VK.Widgets.Like('vk_like', {type: 'button', height: 20});
</script></div>
```

is forms `<a class="like_counter_wrap fl_l" onclick="openFullList();">`. The idea is to prevent function "openFullList();"

Comment: What you mean with "hide the function"? Remove it?

Comment: Okay, and *why* do you need to do this? What's your intent?

Comment: Yes, I want remove it some how.

Comment: There is a list, that opening when i click the link. I don't want that this list will be opened.

Comment: Just get a reference to the `a` and set `a.onclick=null`.

Comment: But if I have many a.onclick? All a.onclick will be null...

Comment: Give this particular `a` an `id`, and then `document.getElementById('id_of_a').onclick=null;`. The simplest way would be to remove the onclick from the file though.

Comment: "*get a reference to **the** `a`*", not **all** `a` elements.

Comment: set an Id for that a and select it by its Id.. Then set onclick=null

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is client side code, meaning ALL code is viewable by somebody in a browser, as long as they dig deep enough. Sure, you could minify it like tyme suggests, but be aware one can still use a tool like the Chrome web inspector to find the exact line number and snippet of code run for the click event.

Basic answer: if the flow of how your code runs must not be "visible" to the end client, JavaScript is not the language you want to be using.

Comment: If I am wrong correct me, From comments, he wants to prevent calling the function openFullList() on onCLick event. I dont think he wants to hide any code to end client. Is @Alex answer related to this question...

Comment: Yes. Don't meter if the user go to the chrome inspector. The function mustn't be work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your markup to this

```
<a class="like_counter_wrap fl_l">
```

now you  wrap your function in a script tag and place it before the closing tag `body` (for performance)

```
<script>
    function openFullList(){
         //do something
    }

    var button = document.querySelector(".like_counter_wrap");// document.querySelector("a"); 

    button.addEventListener("click",openFullList,false);
<script>
```

or put it in a file and bind it to your HTML like this

```
<script src="script/myscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi what if you do like below,

```
   <a class="like_counter_wrap fl_l" onclick="openFullList(true);">link1</a>
   <a class="like_counter_wrap fl_l" onclick="openFullList(false);">link2</a>
```

then script as follows,

```
function openFullList(val) {

    var showList = val;
    if (showList)
    {
       //allow your function to execute
    }
    else
        return false;     //dont allow the function to execute simple by returning false

}
```

So, If you want to show list if user clicks on the link then pass true while calling the function or else pass false...hope it helps...